# trying to get the values from the end of lines and add them together

Tags: python, function, slice

I'm attempting to get the cost (the values at the end of each line) total from all the logs but I keep getting the error " slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method
."  Each line has varying length before the value. This code does not yet add the cost but I'm making sure I'm getting.

log record entered into function (rec.dat):
*this log would be the record entered into the function

@ 2014 2 14 00:03:01 Matt "login" 0.01

@ 2014 2 14 02:06:12 Mary "login" 0.01

@ 2014 2 14 17:12:05 Mary "cd ~/cs150/projects" 0.01

function:

## the goal of the function is to add how much the cost would be for all actions (in this case cost should end up totaling .03)

```
def cost(rec):
    s = Scanner(rec)
    cost = 0
    line = s.readline()
    for i in range(0, len(rec), 1):
        info = len(line) - 3
        n = float(info)
        price = line[n:0]
        cost += price
        line = s.readline()
    s.close()
    return cost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `float` for slicing, replace:

```
n = float(info)
price = line[n:0]
```

with:

```
price = line[info:0]
```

You don't need `n` variable at all.

Comment: When I do that the price comes out blank when I attempt to print it to check the value

Comment: @user3346105 I think it's separate question, and I don't really know what the code is supposed to do. Consider creating a separate question  with details if you are lost. Thanks.